# How to make ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock return false without entering into the function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

After ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock  execution it gets  exception as 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is null or undefined'.
How to make the ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock  execution return false. or redirect to the page after alert?

```
 if (duplicate >= 1)
        {
           ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Duplicate", "alert('Duplicate Data Exists.');", false);
          // Response.Redirect("ApplyNow.aspx",false);

        }
```

Comment: post code.....! that is required. and BTW `object is null or undefined` occurs when element isn't found in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Duplicate",
                            "alert('Duplicate Data Exists!');", true);
```

try this

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Set the location (the browser's url) with the full path to the next page.

Include `true` as the final argument of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to add `script` block tags around your code.

```
string scr = @"
    alert('Duplicate Data Exists.'); 
    location = 'http://localhost:57113/path/to/page.aspx';
";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myScript", scr, true);
```

...

I just noticed how old the question is. Oh well, maybe it will help someone.